# How to update the changed values of matrix elements of posing bone during running script

Tags: python, scripting, bones

I wrote the belowing script to rotate a mesh object and single pose_bone by operating thier matrices respectively.

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix, Euler
import math

#-----------------------------------------
def rotator(angle, axis, mat4x4):
    rot   = Matrix.Rotation(angle, 4, axis)
    trans = Matrix.Translation(mat4x4.translation)
    return trans * rot * trans.inverted()

#-----------------------------------------

angle = math.pi / 6

obs = (
    bpy.data.objects['Cube'],
    bpy.data.objects['Armature'].pose.bones[0]
#    bpy.data.objects['Armature.001'].pose.bones[0]
    )
attr = (
    "matrix_world", 
    "matrix"
    )

for ob, mt in zip(obs, attr):

    print("="*20 + "\n" + ob.name)

    print("Before")
    mat = getattr(ob, mt)
    print(mat)

    mat = rotator(angle, 'X', mat) * mat
    setattr(ob, mt, mat)

    print("After")
    mat = getattr(ob, mt)
    print(mat)
```

After executing the script, both were rotated according to the plan.
Printing the matrix elements during execution, the matrix of the object got the expected change. On the other hand, the matrix of the bone did not change at all.
[image]

```
====================
Cube
  Before
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000, 0.0000)    |
            (0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>   |
  After                                         | CHANGED
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)   V
            (0.0000, 0.8660, -0.5000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.5000,  0.8660, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
--------------------
Bone
  Before
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)    |
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>   |
  After                                          |  NOT CHANGED!
<Matrix 4x4 (1.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)    V
            (0.0000, 0.0000, -1.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 1.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000)
            (0.0000, 0.0000,  0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

Would you tell me what is wrong. Blender 2.79 and 2,77a

Thanks

Comment: Could put a `scene.update()` before you print the value.  The scene isn't updated for each operation in code.  Will give spasmodic results like above, an objects matrix world as opposed to a pose bones matrix. Wouldn't recommend using scene update in a loop,  to test  values..  (that you already know value cos you've set it).  Rather have one scene update and loop again to show changed values.

Comment: @batFINGER  Thanks. I have solved this problem by your comment. 
I want to understand the matrix_channel, but  I could not find a better reference. For analyzing the matrix, I tried to acquire the values of the matrix when the bone was rotated several times.  Therefore It is a script for investigation only.